# Resolution 768 x 1280

Tags: android, resolution

Is it possible to make a layout for this nexus 4 resolution . my app give problem with custom views. 
i have 
layout-hdpi
layout-xhdpi
layout-xxhdpi

i know xhdpi includes 768 x 1280 and 720 x 1280 .

[image: one x]
 [image]

Comment: `xhdpi includes 768 x 1280 and 720 x 1280` no it does not. read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms again.

Comment: yes in your layout file there is an option that you can see how it looks on certain devices. choose nexus 4 and then apply your layout on this device and use fixed width's and height's so that it fits only there. also you dont need 3 layouts as you mentioned above. You can use http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html to generate your icons to support the layout you would like to use...

Comment: when i change for nexus 4 the layout mess up in one x. give me a solution guys.

Comment: Please post your layout xml. We cannot know how your layout is messed up without looking at the code.

Comment: @AshrafThaikkat: How did you finally resolve the issue. It would be very kind of you, if you could please share the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dpi only partially depends on resolution. It is a measure of how tightly the pixels are packed on the screen. Thus, it is a function of both resolution, as well as the physical size of the screen.

Saying 768 x 1280 px = xhdpi may be correct for some devices, but incorrect for others. For example, what if you have a 10 inch screen that has that resolution? That would most likely be ldpi.

In order to support multiple screens, please follow this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You may want to use dp's instead of pixels in your layouts for setting widths and heights. You can then customize layouts based on the current width of the device by using layout directories such as layout-sw320dp ("smallest width 320 dp").

Comment: you are confusing dpi for dp. (dot per inch for density-independent pixels)

Comment: I am not, actually. Two devices with a resolution of 768 x 1280 can have different dimensions, and thus different screen dpi (dots per inch, like you said). One may want to use dp (density-independent pixels) to support screens of different physical sizes. Edit: I have edited my answer to be clearer.

Comment: ok. was not really sure why you would bring up dpi, talking about dp only seemed sufficient.

Comment: To educate the op what dpi stands for in ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, etc.